# Java OOP - Learning instance of element of Array, for simulating human life ... Mating and new Borning

Tags: java, class, oop, instance, simulate

as you can see, probably I exaggerated this topic. Here is the what i need;

I have a 5-6 classes. and i simulating , when this classes meeting on same location, if they same class with opposite gender, they will be mate. and a baby will born with same class.

But i confused here. I am matching classes with ArrayList and for loop (i and j nested loop).

that's what i need ;

```
if(male Xclass   matches   female Xclass){   //actually here i dont know classes
  Xclass x = new Xclass();                   // i have just elements i and j
  list.add(x);
} // something like that , but how can i know which class they have and how 
  // can i create a new class while i don't know this.
```

**Sorry for bad english, Thank you :)

EDIT: I meant same class with different gender; there are classes A,B,C,D and gender is just variable (private int Gender; //1 for male,0for female and it is random value , 1 or 0) i have a also loctaion x,y class. male A and male A cant mate male A and female A can mate male B and female C cant mate i mean this. sorry for bad experession

Answer (score 3):

So do you mean like this (it's disturbing)? It's weird what you mean by classes of the same type and then different. From your example you only have one class. If I understand correctly you want to model something like this.

```
class Person {

  public enum Gender {

     Male,
     Female;
  }

  public enum SocialClass {
    Royal,
    Peasant,
    Barbarian;
  }

  public final Gender gender;
  public final SocialClass socialClass;

  public Person(Gender gender, SocialClass socialClass) {
     this.gender = gender;
     this.socialClass = socialClass;
  }

  public Person meet(Person person) {
    if (person != this && person.socialClass == this.socialClass && person.gender != this.gender) {
       return new Person(Math.random() > .5 ? Gender.Male : Gender.Female, this.socialClass);
    } else {
       return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
List<Person> people = ...// however you got your list
Person person = randomRemoveFrom(people);
Person otherPerson = randomRemoveFrom(people);

Person child = person.meet(otherPerson);
if( child != null) {
   System.out.println("New Person instance?");
} else {
   System.out.println("No new person");
}
```

Comment: add a 'class' variable to person, i think. Then check that they match as well

Comment: Um that's just how classes work, the List<Person> sort of is a way of saying they are the same type.

Comment: i think OP means social classes haha

Comment: Haha oooooh wow that is like an ambiguous word right there in this case

Comment: I meant same class with different gender; there are classes A,B,C,D and gender is just variable (private int Gender; //1 for male,0for female and it is random value , 1 or 0)
i have a also loctaion x,y class. 
male A and male A cant mate
male A and female A can mate
male B and female C cant mate
i mean this. sorry for bad experession

Comment: Also i Inderstand that you creating a new person in your code. That's okay. But this is just for person. I dont know how can I do this with a lot of classes. I have a 1 Parent class for all this objects. finally, can you explain this part ; ...> .5 ? Gender.Male : Gender.Female...

Comment: Ok so this is done then, Male and Female are an enum, and SocialClass is your A, B, C, D.

Comment: The greater than .5 is just a 50/50 random chance of it being a boy or a girl. Math.random() returns a double between 0 and 1

Comment: oh okay right, i got it. i just didn't know what means ? and : thankss

Comment: Oh sorry yyeah it's a short hand basically for if/else where if the conditional is true, the value after the `?` is used and if it is false, the value after the `:` is used.